# Write data to JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I'm trying to write a list of habit objects to a JSON file, but I can't figure it out. I'm doing this because I want to use this JSON file with node.js.

I've created a section with a class called "habits" that I want to fill this JSON file with, the section itself gets the habit objects from this piece of code:

```
var addHabit = function () {
        var $new_habit = {
            "name":"",
            "value":0,
            "goal":0,
            "html": null
        }

        if ($(".habit-input input").val() !== "") {
            $new_habit.name = $("#habitinput .name").val();
            $new_habit.value = $("#habitinput .value").val();
            $new_habit.goal = $("#habitinput .goal").val();

            $new_habit.html = $("<p id="+uid+">").html("<span class=\"name\">"+$new_habit.name+"</span> <span class=\"val\">" + $new_habit.value + "</span>/" + "<span class=\"goal\">"+$new_habit.goal + "</span>"+
            "<button class=\"plus\">+</button><button class=\"min\">-</button><button class=\"delete\">x</button><button class=\"mod\">modify</button>");
            console.log($new_habit);
            $(".habits").append($new_habit.html);
            $(".habit-input input").val("");

            $("#"+uid + " .plus").on("click", function (event) {
                var val = parseInt( $(this).parent().find(".val").text());
                $(this).parent().find(".val").text( val+1 );
                event.preventDefault();
            });
            $("#"+uid + " .min").on("click", function (event) {
                var val = parseInt( $(this).parent().find(".val").text());
                $(this).parent().find(".val").text( val-1 );
                event.preventDefault();
            });
            $("#"+uid + " .delete").on("click", function (event) {
                $(this).parent().remove();
                event.preventDefault();
            });
            $("#"+uid + " .mod").on("click", function (event) {
                var val = parseInt( $(this).parent().find(".val").text());
                var name = parseInt( $(this).parent().find(".name").text());
                var goal = parseInt( $(this).parent().find(".goal").text());
                $(this).parent().find(".val").text(val = $("#habitinput .value").val());
                $(this).parent().find(".name").text(name = $("#habitinput .name").val());
                $(this).parent().find(".goal").text(goal = $("#habitinput .goal").val());
                event.preventDefault();
            });

            uid++;
        };
    };
```

I want to read the section "habits" into the JSON file so I can use it in this node.js file:

```
var express = require("express");
var url = require("url");
var http = require("http");
var fs = require('fs');

var port = 3000;
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/client"));
//logger component
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("[LOG] %s %s", new Date(), req.url);
    next();
});

http.createServer(app).listen(port);

//clients requests habits
app.get("/habits", function (req, res) {
    console.log("Habits requested!");
    res.sendfile('Habit/client/habits.json');
});
```

What I hope to achieve is that when I go to `localhost:3000/habits` in my browser that I get all the habit objects in JSON format.

At the moment when I go to `localhost:3000/habits` I get this `{"type":"Buffer","data":[123,13,10,32,32,32,32,34,121,101,121,34,32,58,32,49,50,13,10,125]}`

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try `res.json(habits.toString())`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Actually try `res.sendfile('Habit/client/habits.json')`.

Comment: That works for displaying what's in the JSON file at the moment, but the main problem is writing to the JSON file, got any ideas for that? (I will edit in your solution into the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a buffer back from the GET/habits. Need to convert it to a something you can read

try calling `toString('utf-8')`

OR

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```